# How to separate a database by sections? in Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello everyone and good day, I have a problem and I need to separate my database from Firebase sections and then my app is like a "blog" and needs to be separated by sections such as "culture" "food" or Things like that, I just want a section to show only that section and in another section show only what is published in that section

I do not know how to do it would be of great help if you gave me instructions
Thank you for your attention

the references codes:

```
 // USER REFERENCES
 public static DatabaseReference getUserRef(String email) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Userrs")
            .child(email);
}
public static FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}


// POSTS REFERENCES
public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("PostKeys");
}
public static Query getPostQuery() {
    return getPostRef().orderByChild("TimeCreatedKey");
}
public static DatabaseReference getMyPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyPosts")
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}



 // USER ID
  public static String getUid() {
    String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}



// RECORD

public static DatabaseReference getMyRecordRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_RECORD)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}



public static void addToMyRecord(String node,final String id) {
    FirebaseUtils.getMyRecordRef().child(node).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            ArrayList<String> myPostCollection;
            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                myPostCollection = new ArrayList<>(1);
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            } else {
                myPostCollection = (ArrayList<String>) mutableData.getValue();
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}
```

thw JSON archive:

```
   {
  "commentsVideos" : {
  "Jojo" : {
    "-KgonW-KMeWxS-JZQA7k" : {
      "commentIdV" : "-KgonW-KMeWxS-JZQA7k",
      "commentV" : "Jajajaja",
      "timeCreatedV" : 1491239572095
     },
     "-KgpnaW3_QisX7LSjE9T" : {
       "commentIdV" : "-KgpnaW3_QisX7LSjE9T",
       "commentV" : "Alohaaaaa",
      "timeCreatedV" : 1491256371764
    }
   }
  },
    "my_posts" : {
    "a@a,com" : {
    "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn" : true,
    "-Kgl9aYUKSRL72TcILtQ" : true,
   "-KgonvtLrtYGQJlnmpO6" : true,
   "-Kgpb14DgJ2qD6wWU8XM" : true
   }
   },
  "my_postsVideos" : {
   "a@a,com" : {
    "-Kgkva-UzSRa0Q-Ohhy7" : true,
   "-Kgkyf0TLujgvJ8OzZHc" : true,
   "-Kgl6QrqVFxMy4COu-kX" : true
   }
  },
  "posts" : {
   "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn" : {
    "numComments" : 0,
    "numDislikes" : 0,
     "numLikes" : 0,
     "postId" : "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn", 
   "postImageUrl" : "post_images/image:49653",
    "postText" : "Jojo",
   "timeCreated" : 1491101025777
  },
  "-Kgl9aYUKSRL72TcILtQ" : {
     "numComments" : 0,
    "numDislikes" : 0,
    "numLikes" : 1,
     "postId" : "-Kgl9aYUKSRL72TcILtQ",
    "postImageUrl" : "post_images/image:49651",
     "postText" : "Xd",
    "timeCreated" : 1491178516317
  },
  "-KgonvtLrtYGQJlnmpO6" : {
    "numComments" : 0,
   "numDislikes" : 0,
   "numLikes" : 0,
    "postId" : "-KgonvtLrtYGQJlnmpO6",
     "postImageUrl" : "post_images/image:50614",
    "postText" : "Xd",
   "timeCreated" : 1491239682259
    },
   "-Kgpb14DgJ2qD6wWU8XM" : {
    "numComments" : 0,
     "numDislikes" : 0,
     "numLikes" : 0,
     "postId" : "-Kgpb14DgJ2qD6wWU8XM",
     "postImageUrl" : "post_images/image:50624",
   "postText" : "Xdxd",
    "timeCreated" : 1491253076830
   }
  },
 "postsV" : {
  "-Kgkva-UzSRa0Q-Ohhy7" : {
   "numCommentsV" : 0,
   "numDislikesV" : 0,
   "numLikesV" : 0,
    "postIdV" : "Jojo",
   "postVideoUrl" : "post_videos/40925",
    "timeCreatedV" : 1491174581878
  },
 "-Kgkyf0TLujgvJ8OzZHc" : {
   "numCommentsV" : 0,
   "numDislikesV" : 0,
   "numLikesV" : 0,
   "postIdV" : "Juju",
   "postVideoUrl" : "post_videos/40923",
   "timeCreatedV" : 1491175388835
  },
   "-Kgl6QrqVFxMy4COu-kX" : {
   "numCommentsV" : 0,
   "numDislikesV" : 0,
   "numLikesV" : 0,
   "postIdV" : "Jajajaj",
   "postVideoUrl" : "post_videos/40925",
   "timeCreatedV" : 1491177686056
  }
},
"posts_dislikeds" : {
  "a@a,com" : {
    "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn" : true,
    "-Kgpb14DgJ2qD6wWU8XM" : true,
    "Juju" : true
  }
},
"posts_liked" : {
 "a@a,com" : {
  "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn" : true,
  "-Kgpb14DgJ2qD6wWU8XM" : true
 }
 },
"posts_likedVideos" : {
"a@a,com" : {
  "Jajajaj" : true,
  "Jojo" : true,
  "Juju" : true
 }
 },
 "user_record" : {
 "a@a,com" : {
   "commentsVideos" : [ "-KgonW-KMeWxS-JZQA7k", "-KgpnaW3_QisX7LSjE9T" ],
   "posts" : [ "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn", "-Kgl9aYUKSRL72TcILtQ", "-            KgonvtLrtYGQJlnmpO6", "-Kgpb14DgJ2qD6wWU8XM" ]
}
},
"user_recordVideos" : {
 "a@a,com" : {
  "postsV" : [ "-Kgkva-UzSRa0Q-Ohhy7", "-Kgkyf0TLujgvJ8OzZHc", "- Kgl6QrqVFxMy4COu-kX" ]
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be done in 3 steps, add a category to your object, index it, query by orderBy and equalsTo. The new attribute category will allow you to perform a query where only the objects that fulfill the condition are retrieve. Then, the index will speed up the Firebase response process, if you don't index it, you will see a message asking you to it in the console. Then the query you are doing can be placed in any Activity or Fragment.

1.- Add the attribute to your object:

```
"posts" : {
   "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn" : {
    "numComments" : 0,
    "numDislikes" : 0,
    "numLikes" : 0,
    "postId" : "-KggY-LUpys-0ZOhy8zn", 
    "postImageUrl" : "post_images/image:49653",
    "postText" : "Jojo",
    "timeCreated" : 1491101025777,
   "category": "food"
  }
}
```

2.- The index should be something like

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "posts": {
      ".indexOn": ["category"]
    }
  }
}
```

3.- `reference.orderByChild("category").equalTo("food")`

I don't think it is a good idea to separate the node "posts" by category, like "posts-food", "posts-culture", because if the blog grows then you will need to retrieve all your post by other attributes, like creation or most liked, etc.

I was asked in the comments for more details, so:

1. If there is anything before the section you want to see then, add an
   onClickListener to the item leading to the next section. Inside of
   it add an 'startActivity' passing and 'Intent' which must contains
   'putExtra' so in the extras the section name will be pass
2. Then in the next Activity get the extra with 'getExtras()' and pass
   that extra to the 'reference' above
   `reference.orderByChild("category").equalTo(extraCategory)`
3. Here you should add an 'addValueEventListener' to the 'reference'
   the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) covers about it
4. Inside the 'ValueEventListener' you have to reflect the
   'datasnapshot' to your model
5. With that data, populate a recyclerview or any UI

Comment: Hola @cutiko a lo que me refiero es, que como lo implemento digamos estoy en un navigation view y digamos al dar un click necesito que vaya a una seccion, puedo usar el codigo que me diste en el paso numero 3?

Comment: I'm going to add it int answer

Comment: thanks, And the last question if I want the reference to change it in this way would it be okay?

Comment: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "posts":{
        ".indexOn":["category"]
      },
        "postsV":{
          ".indexOn":["categoryV"]
        }
 }
}`

Comment: doesn't seem right to me, index inside index? why? Firebase nodes most be simple, max nesting is 2 no more. In that example read and write are available for every user even if they arent login

Comment: So I have to do a fragment for each section? @cutiko

Comment: You could do it like that and then there is no need to receive the getExtras, so each fragment implements 'reference.orderByChild("category").equalTo("fragmentPurpouse")' But if you use an Activity before then the getExtas make 1 Activity that change accordingly to the previous selection pass as an extra in the intent with putExtra

Comment: Hello and solve that thanks to you really have been of great help now I have a last problem that I do not know how to order in chronological order that the publications can be seen from the most recent to the oldest

Comment: There is another method in firebase called orderByChild() you would have to use the timestamp of creation, always use the server timestamp and set it when the object is created with this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue and be carefull is a map but in your app object most be a long... maybe a double can remember now